# Assigning a value to a certain number of rows within a "by" group - SAS

Tags: sas

I've spent quite a lot of time on Stack Overflow looking for answers to other questions, but I'm really stuck on this one, so I'm finally asking a question!

I have a dataset of fish in SAS, with:

1. a unique ID for each angler
2. three different variables with number of fish released in each category by that angler: **over legal size**, **under legal size**, and **released dead**
3. a sequential number (fishno) based on the number of rows for each ID; 1 to the last row of that ID.
4. **Variable to be created**: Disposition--could be either character variable with "legal" "under" "dead" options or even numeric values of 1-3.

It was originally set up with one row per unique ID, but I set it so that now there is one row per fish discarded (i.e. if there were 3 legal size and 2 undersize fish, I now have 5 rows).

I need to assign, by unique ID, whether each row/fish was released legal, undersize or dead. In the previous example, for a unique ID, I'd need 3 rows assigned to a Disposition of "legal" and 2 rows  assigned to a Disposition of "under".

I've tried first.var statements along with if-then-do statements; played around with macros; nothing worked quite right and I'm pretty stuck here. Is there some sort of random assignment I should try? Is there a much easier way that I'm missing?

Example of the data below...

THANK YOU!!

Data in Excel format

[image: Data in Excel format]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the FISHNO variable, there needs to be some method for assigning each fish as legal, dead, or undersize. The following code will assign the disposition in the that order:

```
data have;
input ID LEGAL DEAD UNDERSIZE FISHNO;
datalines;
15 1 0 1 1
15 1 0 1 2
29 2 0 2 1
29 2 0 2 2
29 2 0 2 3
29 2 0 2 4
38 1 0 1 1
38 1 0 1 2
53 1 0 1 1
53 1 0 1 2
55 1 0 1 1
55 1 0 1 2
;
run;

data want;
set have;
if legal>0 and legal>=fishno then disposition = 'legal';
else if dead>0  and legal+dead>=fishno then disposition = 'dead';
else if undersize>0 and legal+dead+undersize>=fishno then disposition = 'under';
run;
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much!! I knew there had to be an easier and more elegant way to do it and that I was stuck seeing the forest for the trees. I didn't realize that just adding the variables up and using fishno to assign it would work for unique IDs, but it makes sense.